# symfony2 form - store entity into database

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to store some field of a form into database, using this code:

```
$data = $form->getData();
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em=persist($data->getCompany());
$em->flush();
return $this->redirectToRoute('target_success');}
```

But I get following error:

```
Attempted to call function "persist" from namespace "site\formBundle\Controller".
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: persist is an `Entity Manager` method, not a php function

Answer (score 1):

`$em=persist ...` should be `$em->persist(...);`

Furthermore I wonder if it is going to work. Does `getCompany()` return an entity?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @vonbrand I think it does answer the question just fine (particularly about the specific error that has been raised) - it's a code typo.

Comment: Please, use comments to ask clarification questions. Don't include them in the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

$em->persist() must have an instance of an entity object as its parameter. The persist operation tells Doctrine you want this entity to be written to database. You can't give an individual field to persist(), it writes the whole object. Also you appear to be trying to write a form back to the database. You need to pass the form to an entity object, then persist that object to database. Have you created an entity class yet?

I'm not sure why you need to write back fields to database one by one (this is a very odd requirement).

There's no point in me suggesting any code yet as it's not clear if you've got an entity class or not, so I can only suggest you take a good read of [Symfony's simple form guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). This shows you how to define your entity, how to create a form, how to copy the submitted form back to your entity object, then how to write your entity object to database.

Comment: ok I understand, there is a way to create the database table automatically or have I to create it by hand,

Comment: You need to define the table as an entity class. The entity class defines how the table is structured, and each instance of the entity represents a row in the table. Assuming you're going the Doctrine route, see this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html